# React-Native: How to save data before app is closed

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, react-component

I am writing a react-native app which needs to store a string before it's getting closed or background. When the app starts, it needs to retrieve the string again. (I am using expo for development)

I tried to store the data in `componentWillUnmount()`, however the function is not called when I close the app.

This is the function to store data.

```
_storeData = async () => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('data', 'savedData2');
  console.log("done storing");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}};
```

I am calling `storeData()` as below:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
 console.log("unmount")
 this._storeData();
}
```

First, I thought it doesn't store data because I am calling an asynchronous function in `componentWillUnmount()` which might be cancelled before finished, however I don't receive the `unmount` log either.

Comment: did you manage to make it work (store data when app is closed)? How?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to detect when the app is closed in react-native.

You can detect when the app goes in background using AppState,  try checking it out in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a slightly modified version of the code from the docs found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) that works well.

On the component in which you want to save the data when going to background you can add something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
    this._recoverData();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState === 'background' || nextAppState === 'inactive') {
        this._storeData('dataToSave');
    }
};
```

With AppState you will be able to control when the app goes to background and also when it becomes 'active' again.

The _recoverData and _storeData that I call inside those pieces of code are async functions that use the AsyncStorage, so your method shouldn't be a problem.

Additionally, on the docs you can find this note:

> This example will only ever appear to say "Current state is: active" because the app is only visible to the user when in the active state, and the null state will happen only momentarily.

Which could be the reason why you don't receive the unmount log (I haven't tried it though).

Answer (score 1):

I have some code that works for me. Basically it checks if app state is active or passive. Passive triggers even when you close app with back button. In my example, I am tracking weather the user is active or inactive in my app.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

export default function App(){
    const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch()//here I send post request to update users state to active
        
        AppState.addEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);

        return ()=>{
            AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
        }
    },[])

    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) =>{
       if(appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active"){
           fetch()// update users status to inactive
       }
       else{
           fetch()// update users status to active
       }
       appState.current = nextAppState;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way if you are using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/en/). Check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html).